# Preserving newlines in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

Whenever I render a JADE template, I get all HTML in a single line. This makes it difficult to read in view-source mode. How can I tell JADE to create HTML which is properly indented?

Here is my template:

```
#application
  p#docs
    a(href='/docs/index.html') Documentation

  p#user-input
    input#msg(name='msg', size='50')
    input#submit(name='submit', type='submit', value='Send a Message')

  ul#messages
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Jade's compiling options set `pretty` to true.

Which can be done in multiple ways depending of how you are compiling them

- From the command line pass the `-P` or `--pretty` flag.
- From express 3.x: `app.locals.pretty = true;`

*(express 2.x used a different syntax: `app.set('view options', { pretty: true });`, see migration guide: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x)*

Then you can do the following

```
#test.     // <-- notice the dot
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
    the printing and typesetting industry. 
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy 
    text ever since the 1500s ,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
```

which will produce

```
<div id="test">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
    the printing and typesetting industry. 
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy 
    text ever since the 1500s ,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled 
</div>
```

Comment: I use Jade from Express, so I did "app.set('view options', { pretty: true });" just after the ".set('view engine', 'jade');", however, I still get all HTML in a single line. I added my Jade template to the question.

Comment: which version of express are you using? In express 3 I think you have to change it from *app.locals* `app.locals.pretty = true`. Check this https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x

Comment: Ah, these frustrating versions... I just started using NodeJS 2 days ago, and I already have to "migrate"... Thanks anyway!