# How do you tell Jade to keep code format when compiling

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using Jade with nodejs and express. When I call res.render on my jade code, it converts it to html. However, the html has no line breaks. Can I tell jade to preserve code formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

express 2.x

```
app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
```

express 3.x

```
app.locals.pretty = true;
```

Scroll down to "View Options" [in this wiki page](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x).

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744681/2081133).